# Elasticsearch - detect words within words typed together

Tags: elasticsearch

If the user types "thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog" on google, it is smart enought to translate it to "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

I want to do the same with the "tools" that elasticsearch provides.

How could I implement it? (not asking for the full code, just some guidance where to look).

I was thinking maybe I could use a n-gram and match it to existing words on the index before submitting the search.

Comment: Yes, Ngram is an valid approach, but have another options like https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Dictionary Decompounder.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html)  You'll have to provide an English dictionary for it to work off of.

(Try /usr/share/dict/words file on Unix systems, or go grab the dictionary file from OpenOffice. )